# how to add user and item metadata in recommendation engine and which python open source tool can give this features

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

Ex :  i have a master file like

```
                           userid    itemid   rating

                              1         2        5
```

another user file, where user related metadata present, metadata could be many :

```
  userid   age

   1       5
   2       8
```

also i have a item file, where item related metadata present. meta data could be many

```
    itemid     item_catagory   item_geo
    1            5               india
```

if i will recommend any item to a user, i want to include these meta information.
i want to know whether matrix factorisation will be helpful and which python open source module has this kind of implementation available.

Comment: I would recommend adding more detail as to what you have tried and code snippets.

Answer (score 4):

To include additional information to recommender system e.g. about an item, user or a recommendation event one of the existing methods for Context Aware Recommender System (CARS) can be applied.

Try starting with [Factorization Machines](http://www.ismll.uni-hildesheim.de/pub/pdfs/Rendle2010_Factorization_Machines.pdf). You can convert Your data to svmlight format and go with reference implementation [libfm](http://libfm.org/). It has the best documentation and there is a similar example where you can find how to prepare Your data. If it has to be Python, there are also many existing implementation, e.g. [fastFM](https://github.com/ibayer/fastFM) [Simpler - pyFM](https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM). If You want to try Julia, maybe You can use my code of [FactorizationMachines.jl](https://github.com/btwardow/FactorizationMachines.jl) as a base :-)

If You will be comfortable with standard FM, check out: [LightFM](https://github.com/lyst/lightfm) and [Field Aware FM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libffm/)

I think FM are one of the most successful and easy to use models for CARS. Please give some feedback how it works for You. If You need different approach I will be happy to help.

Comment: Which one do you find as preferred with Python,  fastFM / Simpler - pyFM?

Comment: I think fastFM should be the first choice - due to more training options (ALS/MCMC/SGD) and better documentation, e.g. [tutorial](http://ibayer.github.io/fastFM/tutorial.html). But if You are planing writing code by yourself the simpler pyFM using only adagrad SGD would be easier to follow. If You feel comfortable with C++, look at reference implementation libfm.org. For scaling computations on GPU, here is an example using Theano: https://github.com/instagibbs/FactorizationMachine/blob/master/factorization_machine.py

Comment: Thank you Bartłomiej Twardowski!

Comment: I have a question related to fastfm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618259/how-to-use-pythons-fastfm-library-factorization-machines-for-recommendation-t