# How to use Python's FastFM library (factorization machines) for recommendation tasks?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of `<user, item>` pairs where each entry records which user bought which item.

e.g.

```
<u1, i1>
<u1, i4>
<u2, i2>
<u3, i2>...
```

I created an encoded dataset with

```
no_of_features = no_of_users + no_of_items
```

and have set output variable `y` to 1, as each of those entries represented the user having bought that particular item.

Note: All y values are 1 in this case.

The encoded dataset looks like this:

```
user1 user2 user3 .... item1 item2 item3 item4 .... y
  1     0    0    ....   1     0     0     0   .... 1
  1     0    0    ....   0     0     0     1   .... 1
  0     1    0    ....   0     1     0     0   .... 1
  0     0    1    ....   0     1     0     0   .... 1
```

Now, I would like to know how to use `fastFM` to generate recommendations for cases `<x, y>` for any user `x` and any item `y`?

Clearly `regression` is out of the picture here. So should I use the `classification` or `ranking` approach of `fastFM`? Also how? e.g. If I use `classification`, do I need to generate instances with `y=0`? If I use `ranking` approach, do I arrange items by the output of ranking approach and recommend those with higher values?

Comment: I think that [Data Science Exchange](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) could be better place for this. But I am not the pro user of stackexchange :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuition from questions about the problem is good - right now, we only have positive examples stored. Those are the situations where the user actually bought the item.

In this case you should go for ranking loss function. Especially when fastFM has Bayesian Personalized Ranking (BRP) implemented. Moreover, in most cases, where the result is presented to the user in an ordered list of recommendations, we should think of preparing recommendations as a ranking related problem. We do not predict rating (stars), like in Netflix Prize.

The BPR is really straightforward method. But there is one crucial thing to understand it - **we do not care about estimated `y` value itself**. What is **important is the order when we sort estimated examples using this output**.

Thus, in the learning phase the positive and negative examples have to be prepared. Look at [fit method](http://ibayer.github.io/fastFM/api.html#fastFM.bpr.FMRecommender.fit) from fastFM documentation. In order to get your negative examples, the simplest way is to get random ones (uniformly distributed) from all available item set. You can only check if this random example is not actually positive (we do not won't to learn anything from this example except regularization ;-)). The random is uniform sampling is working great for the most cases, because the positive input data as You have prepared is often very sparse (e.g. density < 1%). But you can try different sampling for negative examples, for example: using empirical item distribution. It can works better in some settings, but it is more likely that Your "long-tail" will be left untouched (that was my experience). Or maybe You know about something more about Your data that can help here :-)

Comment: So as I understand your answer, I will create roughly equal number of random `<u, i>` pairs (where user `u` has **not bought** item `i`) with `y=0`, and then apply ranking and sort according to output?

Comment: Almost ;-) Just forget about y value. Your y in this case is <i_positive, i_negative>. First, as You said - user bought/clicked this item. Second is random sample. The rest is fine - fit & sort by output. Let me know if it works for Your case :-)