# PySpark how to incorporate user item features while building a recommender?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

PySparks mllib package provides train() and trainimplicit() methods for training a recommendation model on explicit and implicit data respectively.

I want to train a model on implicit data. More specifically item purchase data. Since it is very rare in my case that a user will purchase an item more than once, the "ratings" or "preference" is always 1. So my dataset looks like:

`u1, i1, 1
u1, i2, 1
u2, i2, 1
u2, i3, 1
...
un, im, 1`

where u represents a user and i an item.

I do have a lot of features for users demographics, location, etc. as well as item features. But I cannot incorporate user or item features in `pyspark.mllib.als.train` or `pyspark.mllib.als.trainimplicit` methods.

Alternatively, I have considered using fastFM or libfm. Both are packages for Factorization Machines which implements an ALS solver and frames recommendation as a regression/classification problem. Using those cases I can include the user, item and more features in the training data as `X`. However, the predicted variable `y` will only be a vector of ones (I don't have explicit ratings only purchases).

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

MF in Spark is a simple collaborative filtering implementation based on user-item events(implicit)/ratings(explicit). You can introduce a contextual information for 2D (user-item) recommender by pre-filtering or post-filtering data. For example, you have a demographic information M/F and kNN recommender (can be MF, doesn't matter), for pre-filtering first thing what you are doing is to select only records which have the same context. Than, you running kNN on them. For MF, doing the same way, two models have to be generated - for F and M. Then, while generating recommendation at first step you select the right model. Both techniques are well described in "Recommender Systems Handbook".

Modeling context - FM is a good way to go. Think, this post maybe useful for you: [How to use Python's FastFM library (factorization machines) for recommendation tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618259/how-to-use-pythons-fastfm-library-factorization-machines-for-recommendation-t/36644243#36644243). You will find there how negative examples are introduce for implicit users' feedback. And pay attention for a ranking prediction - mostly for recommendations is a right way to go.

Another option - introduce your own heuristic, e.g. by busting the final score. Maybe you got some knowledge/business goal/other thing that can introduce value for you or the users.